# Android Play Store Testers not finding app

Tags: android, google-play

Having an issue where some beta testers are unable to find the app on the Play Store after already having signed up to test the app. This is only an issue for a few users, other users have found it on the store via the link with no issues. They have been added to the google+ community page.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: Make sure they are logged with the same account and that they have removed your previous app (if they had any).

Comment: Yep they had been but still no luck. Really odd.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will solve your problem or find what it can be : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/189028?hl=en